# Laravel guzzle get response

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle6

I am using laravel guzzle package for get response from this https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction url

```
    $client = new Client();
    try {
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction?id=18a20dbc34082451143c03ac54a2f24d06494d51e68f8fb1211ca0b63a53f37d');
    }catch (ClientException $e) {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', $responseBodyAsString);
    }
    if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200){
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Status code must be 200');
    }

    $body = $response->getBody();
    return $body;
```

I get $body data properly, but when i tried to get $body->block_num then showing me this Undefined property: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream::$block_num error

Comment: Have you tried debugging your $body? Your code doesn't show $body->block_num at all.

Answer (score 5):

You have to decode the `$response` to get it as because it will convert json into an object
 So for example:

```
$response = json_decode($client->request('GET', 'https://eos.greymass.com/v1/history/get_transaction?id=18a20dbc34082451143c03ac54a2f24d06494d51e68f8fb1211ca0b63a53f37d')->getBody(), true);
```

Try This! It will Help You

Comment: You could also directly use `$client->request('GET', '...')->json()`, can't you?